# How can I get past the preparing to install screen in Ubuntu 15.10 installation in Live environment?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb

I am using a Dell Inspiron N4110 Laptop. I have a intel Core-i5 2.5 GHz Processor and 4GB RAM. It's running Windows 10. After downloading a Ubuntu iso from the official page I have created a bootable USB drive. I chose to try Ubuntu after booting from the USB and clicked the install ubuntu shortcut. But, I got stuck in the "Preparing to install" screen. I have tried installing with the third-party software box and update box unchecked.
Please help me. Let me know if you need to know any other information.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I had the same issue this week. My fix was disable the secure boot in BIOS, then when the GRUB menu opens "Try Ubuntu, Install Ubuntu, etc.", press e and edit the install ubuntu option. Delete the "quiet splash" phrase and there we go. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't include the two option that are download updates and download third party softwares and it will work fine!It worked for me.